# InvalidOperationException in ASP.NET when reading a JSON file

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

I am new to ASP.NET. I am trying to read a Json file in ASP.NET. The code is written on Visual Studio 2022. Visual Studio doesn't seem to recognize the JsonSerializer.Deserialize method. I have included references to Newtonsoft.Json and System.Text.Json. When I try to run the code following error is displayed on the browser.
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.

> InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type
> 'Bharath.WebSite.Services.JsonFileProductService' while attempting to
> activate 'Bharath.WebSite.Pages.IndexModel'.

The code with the Deserialize method is pasted below. Can you please give your suggestions on how to Deserialize the json file? If you need more information, please let me know.

```
namespace Bharath.WebSite.Services
{
    public class JsonFileProductService
    {
        public JsonFileProductService(IWebHostEnvironment webHostEnvironment) => WebHostEnvironment = webHostEnvironment;

        public IWebHostEnvironment WebHostEnvironment { get; }

        public string JsonFileName
        {
            get { return Path.Combine(WebHostEnvironment.WebRootPath, "data", "products.json"); }
        }

        public IEnumerable<Product> GetProducts()
        {
            using (var jsonFileReader = File.OpenText(JsonFileName))
            {
                return JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Product[]>(jsonFileReader.ReadToEnd(),
                new JsonSerializerOptions
                {
                    PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true
                }
                );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I downloaded Newtonsoft.Json from Nuget packages to see if I could use the Deserialize method from Newtonsoft.Json. Even after including Newtonsoft.Json the Deserialize method is not recognized. I am not sure what is missing in the code.

Comment: How is your Product class defined? And please post a sample of the products.json file contents.

Comment: I have pasted the class definition below.
namespace Bharath.WebSite.NewFolder1
{
    public class Product
    {
        public string? Id { get; set; }

        public Product(string? id)
        {
            Id = id;
        }

        public Product(string? id, string? maker, string? title, string? language, string? description, string? version) : this(id)
        {
            Id    = id;
            Maker = maker;
            Title = title;
            Language = language;
            Description = description;
            Version = version;
        }      
    }
}

Comment: Sample of the products.json file is below.
[
  {
    "id": "Bhagavatham - Prahaladhan",
    "maker": "Bharath South",
    "title": "Prahaladhan Kathai",
    "language": "Tamil",
    "description": "Prahaladhan Kathai full",
    "version": 6.1
  },
  {
    "id": "Bhagavatham - Ambarishan",
    "maker": "Bharath North",
    "title": "Ambarishan Kathai",
    "language": "Tamil",
    "description": "Ambarishan Kathai full",
    "version": 6.1
  }
]

Answer (score 0):

> InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type
> 'Bharath.WebSite.Services.JsonFileProductService' while attempting to
> activate 'Bharath.WebSite.Pages.IndexModel'.

To solve this issue we have to register the `JsonFileProductService` in the dependency injection,we need to add a single line of code in the Program.cs file:

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<JsonFileProductService>();
```

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion. I have now got past the InvalidOperationException after adding that line. Now I get another error. I have pasted that below.

An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
Unknown location

NotSupportedException: Deserialization of types without a parameterless constructor, a singular parameterized constructor, or a parameterized constructor annotated with 'JsonConstructorAttribute' is not supported. Type 'Bharath.WebSite.NewFolder1.Product'. Path: $[0] | LineNumber: 1 | BytePositionInLine: 3.

Comment: Hi @Venkataraman Narayanan , try to add package `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson` , then add 
`builder.Services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson();` to  switch to NewtonsoftJson serialization.

Comment: Hi Qing Guo,
I added the 2 lines that you have suggested. I still get the error 
"Deserialization of types without a parameterless constructor, or a parameterized constructor annotated with 'JsonConstructorAttribute' is not supported."

Following 2 lines in the code return an error
1) Bharath.WebSite.Services.JsonFileProductService.GetProducts() in JsonFileProductService.cs
+
2)                return JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Product[]>(jsonFileReader.ReadToEnd(),
Bharath.WebSite.Pages.IndexModel.OnGet() in Index.cshtml.cs
+
   Products = ProductService.GetProducts();

...Thanks